# change drawer menu Icon to Back Icon from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-toolbar, hamburger-menu

Actually I was using One MainActivity and multiple Fragments attached to it. 
I want to change Navigation Drawer Menu Icon of toolbar from certain fragments as back icon.And set back pressed event for that icon.
here is my code

```
 drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

Comment: so when you are in fragment on clicking the back will open the navigation menu or something else ? Please add more details about what you exactly want.

Comment: on clicking the back it should call back pressed like normal back button

Comment: which means you need to return to the home page on clicking back at the top. for example. correct ?

Comment: yes. but not home always, whatever the last fragment that should be called

Comment: are you using fragments in navigation drawer with menu or any type tabs?

Comment: I am using using one main activity and remaining all are fragments

Comment: ok then you need to change the action bar menu icon to back arrow when you switch over to fragments.

Comment: yeah exactly, can you please help me in that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115269/discussion-between-ragu-swaminathan-and-uma-achanta).

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?